# JUnit testing for reading JSON files

Tags: java, json, maven, file-io, junit

Suppose I want to write a test(s) for a Java class that would provide a method for reading and parsing external files (to be precise, files would be JSON and I would be using Jackson).

Moreover, I've got some examples of JSON files I'd parse, and I also have a vague idea what kind of Java object this `SomeMagicalReader.readPony("path/to/location/pony.json")` method should return; if I manage to get`readPony` to return a some kind of `PonyObject`, I think have an idea how to test that the produced `PonyObject` is what I expect.

The question I have concerns providing the `readPony` function with the test data. I'm probably thinking about this way too much, but (1) is there an idiomatic "Java + Junit" way of doing that? (= testing a method that reads external files?) Copypaste the contents of the example file as a String variable in the test code? (They're fairly short, but that would still end up looking ugly quite fast.) Place the example JSONs just ...*somewhere* and call `readPony` with the path? (This sounds more sensible.) (2) What would then be a canonical place to put such external JSON test files, if my tests are organized in a Maven style test package hierarchy, e.g. `src/test/java/com/stuff/app/package/SomeMagicalReaderTest.java`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As per maven's [standard directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), I would advise you to put you JSON test files in `src/test/resources` since they **are** test resources. Note that you can (and should) organize your own folders hierarchy under the resources folder (other developers would find it easier to locate specific test resources when fixing or adding some other tests).

So yes you would end up with your JSON files *somewhere* but not *anywhere* if your own test resources hierarchy is good enough (for example, if you think your package structure is well organized with meaningful package names, following it for your test resources hierarchy isn't a bad idea at all).

Comment: So it sounds like you are advocating OP's approach to copy files into `resources` dir and testing those directly, instead of testing the real files that would be in production?  I myself am facing the same dilemma in Junit, and had a hint that this is the most prudent approach to white box testing...

Comment: What's wrong with copying those production files somewhere into your `src/test/resources` folder hierarchy ? Tests built around production data instead of "dummy" data are the best tests.

Comment: Nothing wrong.  I said I think this is the prudent approach.  Just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask yourself what the mission critical code is for your project - reading files or parsing their content. For my projects, parsing was the interesting part, so I placed files to parse as test resources, read them in the unit test to string and pass them to the parser to unit test the parser. It is also possible to include the contents directly in unit tests as big ugly strings, but when you have a dedicated place for test resources, why not use it.

Comment: Definitely, passing string representations of files is ugly.  It is cleaner to create new `File` objects from the test path.

Answer (score 2):

> Copypaste the contents of the example file as a String variable in the test code

I suggest against doing this as it makes modifying the input for your tests more difficult. Also, using an external file makes your tests more flexible. For example, reading an external file allows you to create multiple tests while reusing the basic framework for each test. Of course, this also means that you will need to take some time to design the methods that actually perform the tests.